# PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column services.zip_code does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have 2 models (`Service` and `Town`) with a `:has_many :through` relationship. I want to be able to find every services of a town and every towns of a service.

Also in front I should never be able to see my Town ID so I can link service and town only with the zip_code of a town.

Here is all my migrations

```
create_table :services, type: :uuid do |t|
  t.string :name,     null: false
  t.string :action,   null: false
  t.string :kind,     null: false
end

create_table :towns do |t|
  t.string :name,     null: false
  t.stirng :zip_code, null: false
  t.string :country,  null: false
end

create_table :services_towns do |t|
  t.belongs_to :service
  t.belongs_to :town

  t.string :zip_code, null: false

  t.index :zip_code
end
```

here are my models

```
class Town < ApplicatonRecord
  has_many :services_towns, primary_key: :zip_code, foreign_key: :zip_code
  has_many :services,       through: :services_communes
end

class Service < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :services_towns
  has_many :towns, through: :services_communes
end

class ServicesTown < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :town, primary_key: :zip_code, foreign_key: :zip_code
end
```

`@service.towns` and `@town.services` are working well in my rails console but if I try a more complex search like 
`Service.where(towns: [towns_array])` I got the following error

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column services.zip_code does not exist
```

With this request I would like to have every Services from every Towns I have passed in the array.

I guess the problem are because of my `primary_key` or `foreign_key` but I don't know what to do better

Comment: What's in `towns_array`?

Comment: It would be an array of zip_code like ["27310, "12300", "48700"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your query, try this

```
Service.joins(:towns).where(towns: { zip_code: towns_array })
```

**or**

```
Service.joins(:towns).where("towns.zip_code IN (?)", towns_array)
```

Hope that helps!